# Any minimum 1% tax on taxable-income for low bracket and large capital gains?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax

Is there any 1% minimum tax on taxable-income [similar to AMT for high-income] when you are in low 15% bracket and have substantial long term capital-gains?

e.g. US, single, std-deduction, 2014.
ordinary-income = 16150, capital-gains-LT = 20000.
So Taxable-income (TI) is 25000 [std-deduction+personal-exemption =10150]

Since 15% bracket runs till 36900, cap-gain tax is 0%
Ordinary income that is taxable is only $5000 and at 10%, tax is $500.

But tax software shows tax as $500 + 1% of TI = $500+$250 = $750
[I suspected bug in software, but want to know if I'm missing some tax code]

That is effectively there is a 1% tax on capital-gains. What am I missing?
I thought the tax should be just $500 and no tax on the capital-gains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, lets get it straight. I'm using 2014 numbers and my Intuit tax software:

```
Regular Income: 16150
Capital Gains:  20000
---------------------
AGI:            36150
---------------------
Deduction:       6200
Exemption:       3950
---------------------
Taxable Income: 26000
---------------------
Tax:              603
ACA Tax:          260
---------------------
Total Tax:        863
```

Let's ignore the ACA tax here, it comes into play since you didn't mention anything about the ACA mandate insurance.

Looking at the calculation worksheet ([page D-14 here](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sd.pdf)) - the account is right (the tax amount may be a bit off, since the tax tables are still not updated for 2014).

You have $20000 capital gains, and $6000 ordinary income. Capital gains are taxed at 0, as expected. Ordinary income is taxed at $603, [per the tax tables](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040tt.pdf).

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't aware of this ACA and 1% penalty; I stay outside US so I guess I should get this ACA excemption (Not Lawfully Present). So I believe my tax should be 603 and not 863. [BTW yes there was a mistake in my calculation that my taxable ordinary income is $6000 and not $5000]

Comment: What 1% penalty?

Comment: If no health-care-insurance, the penalty is minimum $95 or 1% of income-above-$10k.  I think this ACA tax is the penalty. http://kff.org/infographic/the-requirement-to-buy-coverage-under-the-affordable-care-act/

Comment: Is this ACA-tax mandatory or I should be able to avoid it? I used the online taxslayer.com website; even when I say I have health-insurance, it still says my final tax is $863. It finds tax-due as $603; but in final Total-tax gives it as $863.   `• Standard or itemized deductions $6,200.00 • Subtract line 40 from line 38 $29,950.00 • Exemption amount $3,950.00 • Taxable income $26,000.00 • Alternative minimum tax $0.00 • Tax due $603.00 • Adjusted Tax $603.00 Total Tax hide details $863.00`

Comment: @KarthikS There's a special form to add to your tax return. These forms have been drafted, but not yet formalized. See here for more details: http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5156.pdf